# How Do I create pipe?

Tags: java, hadoop, cascading

I'm writing a program to manage file i.e, move file (like an object) from directory1 to 2. I wrote a piece of code in cascading, I'm thinking how I can write the "Pipe" to create a flow.

Somebody could help me ?

Thanks.

```
// access path to the file input and output and archiving
String inputPath = args[0];         //Directory in HDFS of the Input
String outputPath = args[1];        //Directory in HDFS of the Input

File inFile = new File(inputPath);
File outFile = new File(outputPath);

FileUtils.moveFile(inFile, outFile);

//Set up the configuration Properties
Properties properties = new Properties();
AppProps.setApplicationJarClass(properties, MoveToArchive.class);
FlowConnector flowConnector = new Hadoop2MR1FlowConnector(properties);

//Create Sources and Sinks Taps
Tap inputTap = new Hfs(new TextLine(), inputPath);
Tap outputTap = new Hfs(new TextLine(), outputPath);

Pipe copyPipe = new Pipe("copy");
copyPipe = new Each(copyPipe, SelectFileFunction(inFile));

FlowDef flowDef = FlowDef.flowDef()
            .setName("archive")
            .addSource("input", inputTap)
            .addSource("output", outputTap);

flowConnector.connect(flowDef).complete();

try{
    if(outFile.exists()){
        System.err.println("file has been moved successfully!");
    }
} catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("file not found in Archive Directory");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pipe is not connected to any source or sink. Think plumbing.

Replace

```
        .addSource("input", inputTap)
        .addSource("output", outputTap);
```

with

```
        .addSource(copyPipe, inputTap)
        .addTailSink(copyPipe, outputTap);
```